# How to divide R data frame into multiple data frames according to time difference of rows?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have these data: [image: Data Frame]

There's 14.865 of these rows/packets.
I want to divide them into smaller data frames according to the 2-nd column (time). 
Division should create many data frames, each having range of 2 seconds: e.g. the first data frame should range from cca 18:49:17.8 to 18:49:19.8. 
But the next data frame should be moved by 1/3-rd of a second, i.e.: range from cca 18:49:18.1 to 18:49:20.1.

My main question is: how to write the code to find the row which is "2 or 1/3-rd seconds lower".

EDIT#1:
Data saved from dput() in a text file (console output was too long).
https://drive.google.com/open?id=195rcvz_YnmbYbWhJr-IHFreoL8HwzNYt

Comment: Can you share data using `dput` ? Nobody can use the data from screenshots. Type `dput(head(df, 10))` in the console and update your post.

Comment: @RonakShah The output of head() gives me the first 10 rows, but the dput() output is too large for copying, as if it outputs whole data frame.

Comment: If you have many columns you can subset them as well. `dput(df[1:10, 1:5])`

Comment: @RonakShah Hi, could you look into it once more, please?